# Flutter released app not working on the device, when installed

Tags: dart, flutter, permissions, release, flutter-dependencies

When I am debugging the app, everything works fine, but after I perform these commands:

```
flutter clean
flutter build apk
flutter install
```

The installed app is not working properly (Not loading data from API). Any ideas?

[image: Screenshot of app]

[image: Screen of app]

pubspec.yaml:

```
name: test_app
description: A new Flutter project.
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  http: ^0.12.0+2
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
```

Comment: check if your http package is in dependencies or devdependencis on pubspec.yaml

Comment: @RubensMelo I've added a screenshot of dependencies

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski Thanks, edited

Comment: For Android you have to add the internet permissions into your AndroidManifest, they are not added automatically and it won't work in release mode :)

Comment: There is a permission package for Flutter, use this for permissions. https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler

Comment: @HarounHajem Those are runtime permissions but internet access is not that kind of permission and you don't have to ask for user "agreement" to grant it. So the package is kind of useless when it comes to internet access permission.

Comment: Oh didn't know you needed special permission for internet. Thanks for the information

Comment: debug using emulator and install using android 9 mobile phone?

Comment: @danypata how can I mark your comment as an answer?

Comment: @MrLalatg I've decided to transform my comment into a full answer. Feel free to upvote it/mark it as correct answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since this is a problem that might concern other developers and the question deserves an answer I've decided to post it as an answer rather than a comment.

When you create a new flutter project, the framework won't add any permissions to `AndroidManifest.xml` or any configurations to `Info.plist` for iOS. This has to be done manually by the developer.

Also, there are some flutter packages that take care of **runtime permissions**, but these permissions require user input (grant permission or deny it). Runtime permissions are sensitive permissions but internet access permission is not in this category, so there's no need for requesting user feedback on it.

To be even more confusing, the flutter framework can do API requests in debug mode or on simulators without Internet permission added to the `AndroidManifest.xml` (maybe in the future we'll get an error/warning) about missing permission from the flutter team, until then, don't forget to add it in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

Comment: For easy copy/paste `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`

Comment: what about IOS build is it gonna have the same issue?

Comment: @RidhaRezzag iOS doesn't require permission for internet connection, but any other permissions like location, bluetooth, have to be specified in the info.plist file of the app.

Answer (score 0):

Below steps work for me

1. Check your flutter channel in terminal

run `flutter channel`

2. If your channel is in `Dev`

`Flutter channels:`
`master`
`* dev`
 `beta`
`stable`

3. Change your channel to `stable`
   run `flutter channel stable`
4. It will ask for flutter upgrade.
   run `flutter upgrade`
5. you final output will be

`Flutter channels:`
 `master`
`dev`
`beta`
`* stable`

6. **Voila!!!**

Comment: In my flutter app Flutter channel indicates on * stable. i am facing the same issue still

Answer (score 0):

You have to check widgets and its parent widgets but maybe its not fix your issue.

**So check this steps. Each step is different, do not use them all together.**

- **1. check widgets** *

It happens most commonly when you are using Expended widget out side the Column or Row.
To solve this error, your child widget must have the expected parent widget. Some of the widget and their parent widgets are:

[image]

Make sure to have the right parent for all the widgets using this Table, and you will be good to go!

- ***2. Use extendBody property of Scaffold widget***

> return Scaffold(
> extendBody: true,
> ...

- ***3. Size configuration***

Your widget dimensions may not have been initialized yet while your screen layout is loading. Try to print logs of size values in debugging. it may not be initialized or 0 value.

- ***4. Dependency injection***

if you are using some dependencies to get size of device or some dependency management packages (As getx) try this steps.

1. Disable packets from fetching data from classes.
2. Define the screen size and dimensions in the page or class where you get the error.
3. Temporarily comment out functions such as `size = sizepackage.getScreenwidth()`; because moving data into the class may cause errors.
4. get size dimensions from intra-class variables. like width = size.width. You can use MediaQueryData with context temporarily.

So example:

if you have Dimensions class for managing your device size.
use like this.

```
final width = Dimensions().getSize().width;
```

not like this:

```
_dimensions = Get.find... or Bloc or other Provider package
final width = _dimensions.getSize().width;
```

***5. if your issue is fixed with this way put some func. to wait provider to load size configuration***. How:

- - extend class with WidgetsBindingObserver
- - put this initState `WidgetsBinding.instance!.addObserver(this);`
- - watch is loaded size veriables or changed variables with `void didChangeMetrics() {`
- - Update your dimensions with their latest version. and refresh state in `didChangeMetrics()` func.

  **setState(() {
  previousSize = newSize;
  });**
- - do not forget to remove WidgetsBindingObserver in `dispose()` func.
    **WidgetsBinding.instance!.removeObserver(this);**

**visit here for details:**

[my medium blog](https://medium.com/@mkiziltay/fluter-ui-error-after-release-release-mode-render-bugs-0cff7a0e72b4)

or

[github blog](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/126820)