# Cannot post https request on run release flutter

Tags: flutter

When i run the app in development mode, the http request launch normally but cannot send request when in release mode.

I tried to add the line `android:usesCleartextTraffic="false"` but with no success.

Comment: have you added internet permission to your app in manifest and in plist file?

Comment: check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/56056160/2315974

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure to enable internet permission, debug mode doesnot require internet permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```